# What is the difference between Android Mobile OS and Android Wear OS?

Tags: android, operating-system, wear-os

Why google created Android wear OS instead of using Android OS in Smartwatches?

Comment: Related in concept: [Difference between embedded Operating System and Desktop Operating System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880643/difference-between-embedded-operating-system-and-desktop-operating-system), except change "Desktop" to "Android" and "Embedded" to "Android Wear"

Answer (score 5):

Google has created a wear OS because the **screen is small** and *it's not practically possible* to **operate apps** which are on smartphones *on a screen of size of a wrist watch* as it would be **too inconvenient**. There is also a **difference in working speed** of processor which can cause considerable delays. So wear app instead contain only **basic features** and *it's mostly used send notifications to the user*.

Answer (score 1):

Android Wear devices have a lot in common with a regular Android device. The tools are the same, and many of the APIs are the same. Pretty much anything you can do on a phone, you can also do on a wearable. The main differences are that Android Wear does not include WebView, and you are not able to access the internet directly - you communicate via the Data Layer API instead. That is the nice part about Android Wear, is that you can leverage all your existing experience with Android on a wearable device, without learning many new APIs.